# Focusing on a textbox in a different page

Tags: javascript, html, button, textbox, focus

How can I create a button that when pressed will open a new page and focus on a certain TextBox there?

It's worth pointing out that I cannot add any scripts to page the button directs to.

JavaScript and HTML based solutions only please.

Comment: You can't. Putting focus on an element requires script, and since you can't add script to the page…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do what you're after if the new page you're opening is on the same domain as the page that is running the JavaScript. If it is not on the same domain then the then you will not have access to the elements within the DOM of that page (see same-origin policy [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)).

If however you are on the same domain and you open the window like so:

```
var childWindow = window.open(...);
```

You should be able to access to elements and focus one via childWindow.document:

```
childWindow.document.getElementById('some_input_id').focus();
```